# git-svn: branches and tags inside trunk. Can it work?

Tags: svn, git-svn

We use subversion repository with following layout:

```
myrepo
-project1
-project2
-projectn
-branches
--project1-test
-tags
--
etc.
```

I want to use git on my computer, so I found git-svn tool. I can not extract only one project because some of them are libraries and I need them all. **The problem is that branches and tags folders are at same level as other project (there is no trunk folder).**

Can I still somehow use this with git-svn? I tried to export it with git-svn using following options

```
git svn clone svn://myrepo -T . -b branches -t tags
```

but it fails.

Comment: Better change the structure to common trunk/branches/tags, because now, if you merge trunk with a branch, you'll get the branch or trunk contents twice in the resulting merge commit.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not allowed to change structure. I plan not to use svn for branching, only git. Can it work this way?